# Java passing variable - downcasting

Tags: java, object, casting, downcast, upcasting

I have a function e.g.

`helloworld(list<object> names)`

I have the following code :

```
List<CustomClass> newMe = new ArrayList<CustomClass>();
```

Now, if i want to pass `newMe` into `helloworld(newMe);`. This is not possible because im down casting. How can i overcome this issue? Do i downcast my list to (Object) and then try to upcast it? is there another way? would appreciate an example.

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the definition of `helloworld` to

```
public void helloworld(List<?> names) {
    //method implementation...
}
```

Take into account that your method won't be able to add or remove elements from the list parameter.

Comment: You can remove elements from the list parameter. You can also add a null reference but that's not very useful.

Comment: @user2336315 you meant `remove(int)`. Yes, you're right but I don't think it's proper to call `remove(int)` in this kind of methods.

Comment: So if i pass it as a generic <?> , i wont be able to directly modify?

Comment: @RoryLester exactly. You cannot modify it since at compile time you don't know which type the list is.

Answer (score 0):

Just use a ? as generic type in your parameter list. Example:

```
public class Foobar {
    public static void helloworld(List<?> names) {

    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<CustomClass> newMe = new ArrayList<>();

        helloworld(newMe);
    }
}
```